# Visual Studio 2015 Go To Definition for CSS class missing

Tags: css, visual-studio-2015

When I right-click on a css class in an html file in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition, i don't see the option to "Go To Definition". Nothing happens if I press F12 either. Intellisense works, but I have no easy way of finding where the class referenced is actually defined.
I've restarted VS, and also looked at a colleague's setup that works fine and can't see a difference. I know it's not the end of the world, but any help much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What project type is this, MVC, web forms, etc?

Comment: Hi. It's an mvc project, affecting both html and cshtml files.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of solutions both 'Extensions and Updates' to Visual Studio:

1. [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) by  Mads Kristensen at Microsoft. This provides F12 'go to definition' and Alt+F12 for 'peek definition'.
2. [Productivity Power Tools 2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerTools2015) by Microsoft. Similar to the above providing Ctrl + Click to Peek Definition / Go To Definition.

My preference would be Web Essentials as I found one of the other power tools features 'Solution Error Visualizer' a bit buggy.

As to your colleague's set up hard to say. Out of the box visual studio sometimes installs web essentials by default.